# What is the ODBC connection string to an Oracle database knowing the JDBC connection string

Tags: oracle, jdbc, odbc, oracle18c

The working JDBC connection to a Oracle 18c database is like this:

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@//the.server.name.org:1580/boilerinfo"
```

What is the correct ODBC connection string to connect to the same database? I tried just `"odbc:oracle:thin..."` but this doesn't do the trick. I then had a look at [www.connectionstrings.com/](https://www.connectionstrings.com/), but couldn't find the JDBC scheme to start with...

#### Additional info

- The machine running the connection string is a CentOS Linux machine if that matters.
- I need the ODBC connection string for a small program which accesses the database in the same way as the old Java program uses the JDBC string

Comment: How about to read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm#ADFNS1155) article? Or just [the same site](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-odbc-for-oracle/) you provided?

Comment: @astentx Thanks for chiming in. The ODBC doco doesn't tell me how the parts in the JDBC string map to parts in the ODBC string. E.g.: Does the JDBC string use TNS or not? Where does the "`thin`" go? etc... - BTW I just added some details that the whole thing happens under Linux.

Comment: Because ODBC is not JDBC. TNS is just a single point of configuration, you are free to use TNS name or host name, port and sid or directly type in TNS entry to connection string. `thin` is type of JDBC driver, so it has nothing about ODBC. You can check [JDBC doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/jdbcthin.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed the Oracle 12c ODBC driver, the `/etc/odbc.ini` entry will look like this:

```
[boilerinfo]
Description = boilerinfo Oracle DB
Driver = Oracle 12c ODBC driver
Database = boilerinfo
Servername = //the.server.name.org:1580/boilerinfo
UserID = MYUSER
Password = MYPASS
Port = 1580
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Is there a way to avoid putting this in some config file? As mentioned in the question I'm after  _a connection string_ (for a small program).

Comment: @halloleo - Instead of using `'DSN=boilerinfo'` as your connection string you can use a "DSN-less" connection string that is simply the DSN values concatenated with semi-colons: `'DRIVER=Oracle 12c ODBC driver;DATABASE=boilerinfo; …'`

Comment: @GordThompson Sounds promising! Will check it out!